# How to only use my max api calls php

Tags: php, api, request, limit, blockchain

I am using the [raw blockchain api](https://blockchain.info/q) and the docs say that I can do 1 request every 10 seconds, how would I make sure that I don't go over this limit? I'd prefer to keep it server side with php. Thank you for the response

Answer (score 0):

After each call to the API add to your internal time counter 10 seconds to know when the next call will be allowed.

```
class ApiRequest{

   private $nextRequestTime = time();

   private function allowRequest(){   
      $local_time = now();     
      if($local_time >= $this->nextRequestTime ){
         $this->nextRequestTime = ($local_time + 10);
         return true;
      }
      return false;
   }

   public function doRequest($request){
      if($this->allowRequest()){
         // process the $request...
      }
   }

}
```

When function `ApiRequest::allowRequest()` returns `false` you know that you should process the request later.